# Priming Sugar Amounts

Tags: priming-sugar

I've always primed my beer at the same rate (5g corn sugar/L) but a recent spate of gushers has made me think that perhaps this is too much - is 4g/L more sensible? or even 3g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 g/L is a reasonable amount of priming sugar. It will add around 1 volume of CO2. Beer fermented at room temperature will contain round 1 volume of dissolved CO<sub>2</sub>, so adding the priming sugar brings the total CO<sub>2</sub> volumes to 2, which is a typical carbonation for many styles.

There are a lot of priming calculators available online. You enter the beer's temperature, volume and desired carbonation level. The calculator will tell you how much sugar to add. [This one](http://kotmf.com/tools/prime.php) comes with a nice explanation of how the calculations work.

If you're getting gushers, there are other possible explanations.

- the beer had not finished fermentation prior to bottling. Make sure the specific gravity is constant over a period of a few days.
- the beer had more dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> than typical. Probably due to low temperatures
- bacterial contamination. Some bug will consume sugar that brewing yeast leaves behind, producing excess carbon dioxide.
- Incomplete mixing of priming sugar prior to bottling. Some bottles will get more priming sugar than others, and will gush. [This question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-can-i-prime-for-bottle-conditioning-without-oxidizing-the-beer) has answers pertaining to mixing the priming sugar completely.